# Zombie.js Click input type image

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I use Node.js along with Zombie.js for scraping. On some pages, I need to click a Javascript link
the part that I want to click is

```
<input type="image" name="ok" src="dialog_ok_apply.png" height="22" width="22" title="OK" class="dialogFocus">
```

How can I do it using Zombie.js? Or is there any alternative to Zombie.js that can handle javascript link?

Comment: I don't know Zombie.js but it seems like you can simulate events on elements. If you want to watch for the events you simulated, have a look at [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/)

Comment: @Logar can you pls show me how can it be done also with the  sinon ?